# peewee not null constraint failed, adding _id to class

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, peewee

Here's the model I'm trying to implement in peewee/python:

```
class Person(BaseModel):
    name = peewee.Charfield(unique=True)
    rate = peewee.FloatField()

class Unit(BaseModel):
    person = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Person)
```

I create the tables, then try creating some dummy data in the database:

```
 from above import Person, Unit

 ben = Person()
 ben.name = "Ben Dover"
 ben.rate = 21.5
 ben.save()

 hour_one = Unit()
 hour_one.person = ben
 hour_one.save()
```

When I run both programs, I get an error on the second one at the `hour_one.save()` line with the following error:

```
peewee.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: unit.person_id
```

I don't know why peewee thinks there's a person_id attribute on person. I thought person.name would be the unique identifying column in that table. I tried replacing `unique=True` with `primary_key=True`, and also tried including both, but the error persists.

I could understand if I hadn't supplied `ben.name`, but I did. So what information is peewee missing that it thinks is null?

Comment: Can you show us your table structure as well?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous There are no existing tables. After defining the models I create them with `create_tables([Person, Unit])`

Comment: Try this: `hour_one = Unit(person=ben)  hour_one.save()`

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous That throws the same error.

Comment: In fact the same error is thrown when no person is specified for hour_one.

Comment: How about `person = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Person, to_field="name")` ?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous I think the problem may have been me creating the database but not deleting it before thinking I was creating it again.

Comment: YES. Use drop_tables() before create_tables().

Comment: @coleifer I knew it would be me missing something obvious while I was messing about. Also, loving peewee so far, thanks for all your work.